# jQuery UI full html pasted in tab control only local

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have a [tab control](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) which works in production. When I host it locally (iis express) it gives me my full page html copied and pasted in a div which firebug reveals.

my js code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    event: 'mouseover'
});
```

the output of firebug (not browser specific error by the way):

[image]

used: (used older versions before, but still have the local bug with the latest versions)

- jquery 2.1.1
- jquery ui 1.11.1

In the screenshot there is this:

```
<div id="ui-id2" ...>
<div id="ui-id4"..>
<div id="ui-tabs-1">I made this one</div>
<div id="ui-tabs-2">I made this one</div>
```

so who makes **ui-id2** and who makes **ui-id4** and why is my complete webform page source pasted at **ui-id2**
and why is this only local?

Disabling the `.tabs` method call in javascript "solves" it, but I like to have the tab control. It works when it is hosted in IIS, only does not work when I run it locally.

can it be related to https://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-jquery-ui-tabs-and-base-tag I have a base tag for url-rewriting.

changing the `a href` of `#ui-tabs-1` of the tab to `http://localhost:62709/#ui-tabs-1` did not work.

Comment: really not clear what your specific problem(s) are. Tabs widegt assigns ID's if none available, but how that is a problem isn't clear. Also not clear what page or behavior differences are between local and remote server

Comment: the divs ui-id2 and ui-id4 are added when I run it locally and the complete html of the full page is added to ui-id2 or 4 so it looks like the same website in an iframe in the same page. only happens locally

Comment: sounds like paths aren't resolving properly in local version. Look in browser console to see where the actual requests are going

Comment: local and remote have the same source...

Comment: that doesn't answer question of path that is actually being requested by browser which can easily be seen in browser console newtork tab

Comment: content of the tab is static html, so what path possibly can be wrong? the jquery libs are all loaded.

Comment: i misunderstood the problem , thought it had to do with ajax loaded tabs. Well obviously something loading in page is different than server version. Not sure why the url was mentioned